# Como fazer que apenas coisas com o status X sejam exibidas na página?

Tags: php

Tenho um site, e nele algumas pessoas podem postar coisas como se fossem notícias, e eu gostaria de dar um jeito que apenas notícias que fossem aprovadas (por membros da equipe) fossem mostradas, já tenho o sistema phpmyadmin pronto, as notícias tem uma nova coluna chamada 'status' e para ser ativada deve ter o status "1". Notícias novas são criadas com o status 0, porém aparecem do mesmo jeito na página pois não há uma restrição, como eu poderia adicionar algum tipo de restrição para apenas as tais notícias aprovadas serem exibidas? (Desculpem se ficou extenso o texto ou mal explicado, é minha primeira vez aqui no site, ainda estou aprendendo)

*(Informações adicionais: A Tabela onde ficam as noticias se chama: noticias, ela possui algumas coisas mencionadas aqui como: autor, revisado por e etc, e a coluna onde fica onde ela é ou não ativada se chama status, 1 para ativado 0 para não

Segue as 2 páginas .php da parte de notícias:

Página onde apenas tem a base (nada demais, todo o código de inserção de notícia se encontra na outra, essa apenas para vocês terem uma base)

```
    <head>
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
google_ad_client: "ca-pub-6295119959637671",
enable_page_level_ads: true
});
</script>
<head>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                <div style="padding-top: 0px;" class="panel-body">
                    <div id="loader" style="text-aling:center;margin-left:50%;">
                        <img src="hk/loader.gif">
                    </div>
                    <div class="outer_div">
                    </div>
                    <!-- Datos ajax Final -->
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
<?php echo $redes_sociales; ?>
            <?php echo $cartel_publicidad; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        load(1);
    });
    function load(page){
        var parametros = {"action":"ajax","page":page};
        $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
        $.ajax({
            url:'kernel/ajax/Body_Noticias_ajax.php',
            data: parametros,
             beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#loader").html("<img src='hk/loader.gif'>");
            },
            success:function(data){
                $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loader").html("");
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Complemento da página onde são mostradas as notícias: (isso é outro arquivo)

```
<?php 
function paginate($reload, $page, $tpages, $adjacents) {
    $prevlabel = "&lsaquo; $lang[196]";
    $nextlabel = "$lang[197] &rsaquo;";
    $out = '<ul class="pagination pagination-large">';

    // previous label

    if($page==1) {
        $out.= "<li class='disabled'><span><a>$prevlabel</a></span></li>";
    } else if($page==2) {
        $out.= "<li><span><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>$prevlabel</a></span></li>";
    }else {
        $out.= "<li><span><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".($page-1).")'>$prevlabel</a></span></li>";

    }

    // first label
    if($page>($adjacents+1)) {
        $out.= "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>1</a></li>";
    }
    // interval
    if($page>($adjacents+2)) {
        $out.= "<li><a>...</a></li>";
    }

    // pages

    $pmin = ($page>$adjacents) ? ($page-$adjacents) : 1;
    $pmax = ($page<($tpages-$adjacents)) ? ($page+$adjacents) : $tpages;
    for($i=$pmin; $i<=$pmax; $i++) {
        if($i==$page) {
            $out.= "<li class='active'><a>$i</a></li>";
        }else if($i==1) {
            $out.= "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(1)'>$i</a></li>";
        }else {
            $out.= "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".$i.")'>$i</a></li>";
        }
    }

    // interval

    if($page<($tpages-$adjacents-1)) {
        $out.= "<li><a>...</a></li>";
    }

    // last

    if($page<($tpages-$adjacents)) {
        $out.= "<li><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load($tpages)'>$tpages</a></li>";
    }

    // next

    if($page<$tpages) {
        $out.= "<li><span><a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='load(".($page+1).")'>$nextlabel</a></span></li>";
    }else {
        $out.= "<li class='disabled'><span><a>$nextlabel</a></span></li>";
    }

    $out.= "</ul>";
    return $out;
}
?>
<?php
    require ('../../global.php');

    $action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
    if($action == 'ajax'){
        //las variables de paginación
        $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
        $per_page = 6; //la cantidad de registros que desea mostrar
        $adjacents  = 4; //brecha entre páginas después de varios adyacentes
        $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
        //Cuenta el número total de filas de la tabla*/
        $count_query   = $link->query("SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM noticias ");
        if ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)){$numrows = $row['numrows'];}
        $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
        $reload = 'furni.php';
        //consulta principal para recuperar los datos
        $query = $link->query("SELECT * FROM noticias  order by id DESC LIMIT $offset,$per_page");

        if ($numrows>0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
?>
<div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $row['imagen']; ?>);background-position: 50%;margin-bottom: 15px;border-radius: 5px" class="articulo">
    <a href="articulo.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
  <div class="contenedor-datos">
        <div class="contenedor-likes">
            <div style="float:left;font-size: 14px;"><i style="font-size: 11px;" class="material-icons">thumb_up</i> <?php echo $row['megusta']; ?></div>
            <div style="margin-left:10px;float:left;font-size: 14px;"><i style="font-size: 11px;" class="material-icons">thumb_down</i> <?php echo $row['no_megusta']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <p><span style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"><span class="datos-noticia"><?php echo $lang[34]; ?>: <?php echo "$row[fecha]"; ?> <span style="margin-left:15px;"><?php echo $lang[35]; ?>: <?php echo "$row[categoria]"; ?><span style="margin-left:15px;"><?php echo $lang[36]; ?>: <?php echo "$row[autor]"; ?><span style="margin-left:15px;"> <?php echo $lang[456]; ?>: <?php echo "$row[autorizado]"; ?> </span></span>
          </span>
            </span>
    </p></div>
    <div style="height: 55px;position: relative;padding: 10px;float: left;width: 55%;background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.86);overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="titlesmallarticulo">
            <a href="articulo.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                <?php echo "$row[titulo]"; ?>           </a>
        </div>
        <div style="color:#ccc;" class="resumen-noticia">
            <?php echo "$row[resumen]"; ?>                <br>
        </div>

    </div>
<div class="detalle-titulo"></div>

    </a>
</div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        <div class="table-pagination pull-right">
            <?php echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);?>
        </div>

            <?php

        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <?php echo $lang[195]; ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Creio que ficou muito extenso os códigos, mas preciso muito disso, e não faço a mínima ideia do que fazer sou novo em .php ;(

Comment: OBS: Se eu uso o comando SQL na database: SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE status = 1 apenas notícias com status 1 aparecem nos registros, então não é erro na database.

Comment: Opa Gui! Obrigado! Creio que aconteceu um pequeno bug no cache e as notícias não estavam sumindo! Porém limpei e fiz como você falou! E Funcionou! Obrigado ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em:

```
SELECT * FROM noticias  order by id DESC LIMIT $offset,$per_page
```

Adicione uma cláusula `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE status = 1 order by id DESC LIMIT $offset,$per_page
```

Isso fará uma busca na tabela e pagará apenas aquelas linhas que tiverem a coluna satus 1

**Cuidado** ao usar interpolação de string para passar dados ao script SQL você está sujeito a [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864)